# How to open a large file with an .tar.xz extension?

Tags: windows-7

I got a 1GB file with an .tar.xz extension.  Apparently, inside this single file is PDF files and ebooks.  How do I open this type of file and read these files?  Does ExtractNow work?

Any simple tools?

Windows 7 64-bit.
IE 8.

Answer (score 23):

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) has a nice, easy GUI that can let you extract `.xz` (and many other) archives.

XZ files are not associated by default, so after installing 7-zip, right-click your `.xz` file and select *7-Zip->Open archive* Then you can double-click the `.tar` file in that to see the `.pdf` file. You can then open it directly or since it is so big, it would be better to extract the `.pdf` file somewhere first.

As for ExtractNow, yes it does have `xz` files in its list of [supported archive formats](http://www.extractnow.com/Usage.aspx#faq). If you already have ExtractNow installed and are familiar with it, then you could certainly use that.

Comment: Oops, my file is .tar.xz!

Comment: Oh. Hee.  Is 7-zip available for Windows 7?  It doesn't say.

Comment: It doesn’t matter. Open the `.xz` file, then open the `.tar` file, then extract the `.pdf` file.

Comment: Yes. 7-zip is available for many OSes and architectures, but like I said, you may as well try ExtractNow since it says it supports [`txz`](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/txz) (xz tar) files.

Comment: 7zip works wonderfully on windows 7

Comment: Should I download the 64-bit .msi or the 32-bit .exe?  My comp is 64-bit.  I'm not familiar with .msi?

Comment: `.MSI` files are Windows Installer files. If your system is 64-bit then you should install the 64-bit one because it will take full advantage of your system (eg compress and extract files much faster and use less memory).

Comment: Used ExtractNow but the file remains as a single file but it's extension has changed to .tar.xz-0! What's the -0? And why is it still a single file?  Did I erase the files?

Comment: I tried to download the 64-bit .msi = saved it to desktop; ran it; it said "installer package not valid and to contact maker." What do I do?

Comment: Okay, so I installed it and extracted the one with the -0 but only half the files are there; half are missing.  Is it because I screwed it up with ExtractNow?

Comment: No, ExtractNow should not have altered the file. Are you sure the original file is correct? Where did you get it? Can you get it again or hash it to confirm it is correct? Try using the *Test* function in 7-Zip.

Comment: Hash it?  Sorry, I'm such a newbie.  What does the test function do?

Comment: Hashing checks all the bytes of a file and gives a number which you can compare to see if they match. It is a way to detect a corrupted file. The test function does a sort of test-extraction to check for corruption. It sounds like the archive file may be corrupted. Can you get another copy or do a check and re-downloaded the corrupted bits? It may be easy or hard depending on where and how you got it.

Comment: I would also note that the reverse is true for 7z. I have been using it for years, but did not realize until now that I could create a .tar, then do "add to archive" again to compress that tar with xz. (I would normally bump it off to a linux machine.)

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz):

> xz is a lossless data compression file format incorporating the LZMA2
>   compression algorithm. While xz can only support one file the
>   convention is to bundle a file that is an archive itself, such as
>   those created by the tar or cpio Unix programs.

You need to decompress the outer `.xz` archive, and then decompress the inner archive. You can use [XZ Utils](http://tukaani.org/xz/), as mentioned by @Journeyman, or [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to extract the files. I recommend 7-zip, as it is more user-friendly.

[image: xz]

[image: tar]

Comment: Can it open .tar.xz?

Comment: Yes. The inner archive is `.tar`, while the outer archive is `.xz`. 7-zip has support for both.

Comment: Hmm...ExtractNow didn't work.  Let me give your solution a try.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you can use [xzutils](http://tukaani.org/xz/), which has a windows port. xzutils' readme also indicates [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) will work

Comment: A windows port?  I'm lost.  I checked it out: how do I use it?

Comment: scroll down to 'prebuilt binaries' and download it. Unzip and use. The documentation also indicates 7zip will work as well

Answer (score 1):

Why don't Windows users just stick with ZIP archives? Well, to extract an archive with a **.tar.xz** extension, then you should get **7-Zip**. After 7-Zip is done installing, right-click on the archive file and select **7-Zip > Extract to *filename*\**; the archive should then be extracted into its own directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using FAR Manager. Just open FAR Manager, click on your .tar.xz and press Shift + F2, it will be extracted to .tar. Then you can open the .tar with WinRAR or also using FAR Manager (by clicking on it and pressing Shift + F2).